# Copying image to another image at specific location

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to copy some area of image to another position of same image. I tried with the code which I got on StackOverflow. I am giving snippet of the code I tried:

```
    roi = frame[ry1:ry2, rx1:rx2]
    roi.shape
    frame = frame.copy()
    frame[:roi.shape[0], :roi.shape[1]] = roi
```

Comment: you can use masking for it

Answer (score 1):

You may play with this sample:

```
import cv2

def roi(frame, x1, y1, w, h, x2, y2):
    # x1, y1: from
    # w, h: size
    # x2, y2: to
    roi = frame[y1:y1+h, x1:x1+w]
    frame = frame.copy()
    frame[y2:y2+h, x2:x2+w] = roi
    return frame


image = cv2.imread('test.png')
image = roi(image, 100, 120, 90, 150, 320, 310)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```